# Count occurrences of elements in string from a list?

Tags: python, string, for-loop, text

I'm trying to count the number of occurrences of verbal contractions in some speeches I've gathered. One particular speech looks like this:

```
speech = "I've changed the path of the economy, and I've increased jobs in our own
home state. We're headed in the right direction - you've all been a great help."
```

So, in this case, I'd like to count four (4) contractions. I have a list of contractions, and here are some of the first few terms:

```
contractions = {"ain't": "am not; are not; is not; has not; have not",
"aren't": "are not; am not",
"can't": "cannot",...}
```

My code looks something like this, to begin with:

```
count = 0
for word in speech:
    if word in contractions:
        count = count + 1
print count
```

I'm not getting anywhere with this, however, as the code's iterating over every single letter, as opposed to whole words.

Comment: for word in speech.split(' '):

Comment: I don't get what the values in your dict are doing, you have a dict btw not a list

Comment: I've added a lot of things in my answer which should give you some extras.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use [`str.split()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.split) to split your string on whitespace:

```
for word in speech.split():
```

This will split on *arbitrary whitespace*; this means spaces, tabs, newlines, and a few more exotic whitespace characters, and any number of them in a row.

You may need to *lowercase* your words using [`str.lower()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.lower) (otherwise `Ain't` won't be found, for example), and strip punctuation:

```
from string import punctuation

count = 0
for word in speech.lower().split():
    word = word.strip(punctuation)
    if word in contractions:
        count += 1
```

I use the [`str.strip()` method](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.strip) here; it removes everything found in the [`string.punctuation` string](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#string.punctuation) from the start and end of a word.

Answer (score 1):

You're iterating over a string. So the items are characters. To get the words from a string you can use naive methods like [`str.split()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.split) that makes this for you (now you can iterate over a list of strings (the words splitted on the argument of str.split(), default: split on whitespace). There is even [`re.split()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.split), which is more powerful. But I don't think that you need splitting the text with regexes.

What you have to do at least is to lowercase your string with [`str.lower()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.lower) or to put all possible occurences (also with capital letters) in the dictionary. I strongly recommending the first alternative. The latter isn't really practicable. Removing the punctuation is also a duty for this. But this is still naive. If you're need a more sophisticated method, you have to split the text via a word tokenizer. [NLTK](http://www.nltk.org/index.html) is a good starting point for that, see the [nltk tokenizer](http://www.nltk.org/api/nltk.tokenize.html). But I strongly feel that this problem is not your major one or affects you really in solving your question. :)

```
speech = """I've changed the path of the economy, and I've increased jobs in our own home state. We're headed in the right direction - you've all been a great help."""
# Maybe this dict makes more sense (list items as values). But for your question it doesn't matter.
contractions = {"ain't": ["am not", "are not", "is not", "has not", "have not"], "aren't": ["are not", "am not"], "i've": ["i have", ]} # ...

# with re you can define advanced regexes, but maybe
# from string import punctuation (suggestion from Martijn Pieters answer
# is still enough for you)
import re

def abbreviation_counter(input_text, abbreviation_dict):   
    count = 0
    # what you want is a list of words. str.split() does this job for you.
    # " " is default and you can also omit this. But if you really need better
    # methods (see answer text abover), you have to take a word tokenizer tool
    # or have to write your own.
    for word in input_text.split(" "):
        # and also clean word (remove ',', ';', ...) afterwards. The advantage of 
        # using re over `from string import punctuation` is that you have more
        # control in what you want to remove. That means that you can add or
        # remove easily any punctuation mark. It could be very handy. It could be
        # also overpowered. If the latter is the case, just stick to Martijn Pieters
        # solution.
        if re.sub(',|;', '', word).lower() in abbreviation_dict:
            count += 1

    return count

print abbrev_counter(speech, contractions)
2 # yeah, it worked - I've included I've in your list :)
```

It's a litte bit frustrating to give an answer at the same time as Martijn Pieters does ;), but I hope I still have generated some values for you. That's why I've edited my question to give you some hints for future work in addition.

Comment: Thanks for the input, but I've moved on from this problem. However, your solution did work! I just didn't want to have to go back and reformat my entire `contractions` dictionary :)

Answer (score 0):

A `for` loop in Python iterates over all elements in an iterable. In the case of strings the elements are the characters.

You need to split the string into a list (or tuple) of strings that contain the words. You can use `.split(delimiter)` for this.

Your problem is quite common, so Python has a shortcut: `speech.split()` splits at any number of spaces/tabs/newlines, so you only get your words in the list.

So your code should look like this:

```
count = 0
for word in speech.split():
    if word in contractions:
        count = count + 1
print(count)
```

`speech.split(" ")` works too, but only splits on whitespaces but not tabs or newlines and if there are double spaces you'd get empty elements in your resulting list.